# Problem plotting a bifurcation diagram

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, nonlinear

I have been trying to plot bifurcation diagram for $R$ vs $X$ (or $Y$) for the following problem

```
    tab = Table[{sol, points} = 
    Reap@NDSolveValue[{Sqrt[-1]*x'[t] == 
    B*x[t] - R*x[t]*Abs[x[t]]^2 - A*y[t], 
    Sqrt[-1]*y'[t] == 
    B*y[t] - R*y[t]*Abs[y[t]]^2 - A*x[t] /. {A -> 1, B -> -2}, 
    x[0] == 0, y[0] == 0, 
    WhenEvent[x'[t] > 0, If[t > 4, Sow[y[t]]]]}, {x, y}, {t, 0.1, 
    20}]; {R, #} & /@ 
    Union[Flatten[points], SameTest -> (Abs[#1 - #2] < .02 &)], {R, 0,
    100, 2}];
    ListPlot[Re@Flatten[tab, 1], ImageSize -> Large, AxesLabel -> {R, x}]
```

I get no error messages but an empty plot. Parameters are flexible so I tried several variations with parameters but didn't succeed in plotting.

Comment: Nothing to plot, `Flatten[tab, 1]={}` is empty!

Comment: You are looking for complex solutions, so the condition $x'[t]>0$ can not be fulfilled. Can be replaced by $Re[x'[t]]>0$, but in this case tab is empty too.

Comment: Yes it keeps giving empty output when even restricting to only real solutions.

Comment: It has something to plot if i give it a nonzero initial condition say $x[0]=1, y[0]=0$ but then it gives errors NDSolveValue:Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at t == 0.`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will show the working code and the result, perhaps this is what is required.

```
A = 1; B = -2; tab = 
 Table[{sol, points} = 
   Reap@NDSolveValue[{Sqrt[-1]*x'[t] == 
       B*x[t] - R*x[t]*Abs[x[t]]^2 - A*y[t], 
      Sqrt[-1]*y'[t] == B*y[t] - R*y[t]*Abs[y[t]]^2 - A*x[t], 
      x[0] == 1, y[0] == 0, 
      WhenEvent[Re[x'[t]] > 0, If[t > 4, Sow[y[t]]]]}, {x, y}, {t, 
      0.1, 20}]; {R, #} & /@ 
   Union[Flatten[points], SameTest -> (Abs[#1 - #2] < .02 &)], {R, 0, 
   100, 2}];
ListPlot[Re@Flatten[tab, 1], ImageSize -> Large, AxesLabel -> {R, x}]
```

[image: fig1]

Comment: Could you say what was the problem with OP's code?

Comment: there are two errors: 1) two equations, and a replacement `/. {A -> 1, B -> -2}` is made one; 2) the condition `x '[t]> 0` is used for the complex function.

Comment: @Alex, yes it works. I have tried to modify the code with $A=10$ and $x[0]=1, y[0]=-1$ to actually see a better/clearer bifurcation behavior, It shows a plot but it is not a very clear bifurcation still. Is there a way to improve this?

Comment: `A = 10; B = -2; tab = 
 Table[{sol, points} = 
   Reap@NDSolveValue[{Sqrt[-1]*x'[t] == 
       B*x[t] - R*x[t]*Abs[x[t]]^2 - A*y[t], 
      Sqrt[-1]*y'[t] == B*y[t] - R*y[t]*Abs[y[t]]^2 - A*x[t], 
      x[0] == 1, y[0] == -1, 
      WhenEvent[Re[x'[t]] > 0, If[t > 0.1, Sow[y[t]]]]}, {x, y}, {t, 
      0, 50}, MaxSteps -> Infinity]; {R, #} & /@ 
   Union[Flatten[points], SameTest -> (Abs[#1 - #2] < .02 &)], {R, 0, 
   20, 0.01}];
ListPlot[Re@Flatten[tab, 1], AspectRatio -> .75/GoldenRatio, 
 ImageSize -> Large, PlotStyle -> PointSize[Tiny], 
 AxesLabel -> {R, x}]`